# Unknown character in column data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the columns seems to have some kind of a special character in front of the data. When I run this query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `stocktake_products` WHERE `stocktake_id` = 4148 AND `stocktake_product_id` = '29153796'
```

I get no results, but running this one:

```
SELECT *  FROM `stocktake_products` WHERE `stocktake_id` = 4148 AND `stocktake_product_id` LIKE '29153796'
```

I am using this field to LEFT JOIN another table
(

```
SELECT
    *
FROM stocktake_scans ss
LEFT JOIN stocktake_products sp ON ss.stocktake_product_id = sp.stocktake_product_id
LEFT JOIN stocktake_staff st ON ss.stocktake_staff_id = st.stocktake_staff_id
LEFT JOIN stocktake_areas sa ON ss.stocktake_area_id = sa.stocktake_area_id
WHERE ss.stocktake_id = X
ORDER BY stocktake_scan_id ASC;
```

) so I do need to use an `"="` syntax rather than `LIKE`.

Fetches correct product. I have tried `TRIM(stocktake_product_id)` but `0` rows were updated. Is there any other way of finding out what that special, invisible character is, and remove it?

Thank you!

Comment: Why you can't use `LIKE`? There is no special, invisible character as well...

Comment: You could just update the filed

Comment: @Legionar I tried using LIKE in the long query, but it has crashed the MySql server. I was making a string out of a bigint datafield, that's why it wasn't returning results. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't link properly to the other table. Could it be that stocktake_product_id in stocktake_scans is an int data type?

Comment: what is the data type of the `stocktake_product_id` column? If it is a numeric data type (like int, bigint), why do you want to compare it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the data types of your columns? It seems to me that `stocktake_id` is integer and `stocktake_product_id` is some other type, like varchar?

That might explain the LIKE operator working and the = operator to fail?

**EDIT:** Just noticed something else: You have single quotes surrounding `29153796`, but you don't have these at `4148`. So you're making a string out of `29153796` and thats why you need to compare using `LIKE`, try it without the single quotes and it should work.

Comment: Yea, I was doing the query wrong. stocktake_product_id in stocktake_products table is a bigint(20). It needs to link to stocktake_product_id in stocktake_scans table, which is int(11). Could that be causing the problem? 29153796 shouldn't be outside the max int value (2,147,483,647 - am I correct?)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `stocktake_product_id` = '29153796' single quotes since its bigint
use 
`stocktake_product_id` = 29153796

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I tried to give answer with my knowledge in c# ,since i have only 1 month experience in c#.[except basics] :(

Comment: I am saying your answer is wrong or right, but this kind of response should be post as a comment. And if you still cannot post a comment, wait till you earn the privilege, or of course try to provide complete answers

Comment: I wanted to write it as comment.i know i have to wait for that to get privilege .thank you @Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can try never use `` on both sides of table_name and column_name

Maybe it's will ok.

```
SELECT *  FROM stocktake_products WHERE stocktake_id = 4148 AND stocktake_product_id = '29153796'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that your `stocktake_product_id` is a numeric column.

Since MySQL will convert the string value ('29153796') to float, which is NOT a precise data type. This can lead to unexpected results.

Please refer to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) to get more info about how data type conversion works.

The relevant part is this:

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison
>   operations:
>
> If one or both arguments are NULL, the result of the comparison is
>   NULL, except for the NULL-safe <=> equality comparison operator. For
>   NULL <=> NULL, the result is true. No conversion is needed.
>
> If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are
>   compared as strings.
>
> If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
>
> Hexadecimal values are treated as binary strings if not compared to a
>   number.
>
> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the
>   other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more
>   ODBC-friendly. Note that this is not done for the arguments to IN()!
>   To be safe, always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when
>   doing comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using
>   BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the
>   values to the desired data type.
>
> If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the
>   other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if the
>   other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point
>   values if the other argument is a floating-point value.
>
> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point
>   (real) numbers.

Using the above knowledge, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `stocktake_products`
WHERE `stocktake_id` = 4148 AND `stocktake_product_id` = 29153796
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so after exporting the data from `stocktake_scans`, removing the data for a specific `stocktake_id`, removing products from the table for that `id` and redownloading the file so the inserts are done again, and updating the `stocktake_product_id` column in `stoccktake_scans`, with the new values for `stocktake_product_id` in `products` table, everything seemed to have worked. I have no idea why it caused a problem the first time around, first time it has ever happened to me.

Thanks to everyone that was trying to give help!